# What advantages does coffeescript offer over javascript specifically with frameworks like BackboneJS?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

As a newbie to coffeescript, I wanted to know what advantages does coffeescript offer over javascript. I know it makes your code more elegant but at the same time slows it down too. Also few of the Javascript features are not inherited in it, still I see many developers migrating to coffeescript specially when they need to use frameworks like BackboneJS.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that coffeescript was designed a few years ago when there was no ECMAScript 6 which brought a few nice features which make writing plain javascript code **easier** and **faster**.

Coffeescript  really boosted speed of development at the time. In fact it become a standard tool of use for the most of the rails projects.
Even if it's slower (eventually it's converted to plain javascript anyway, but I'm not sure if the output js code is slower) for many applications it really makes no difference (we're talking about miliseconds, not seconds).

But now we have 2016, and if I would start a new project today I wouldn't use coffeescript but the new version of javascript or typescript (some would say *choose ELM*).